# Google App Engine 500 internal server error on post requests

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm create Google App Engine instance with code based on vertx and try to habdle post requests.
If i launch my application locally - everything work ok, but if i try to POST request to installed app engine host - all my requests ends with 500 internal server error.

Why? Maybe i forget something?

For example:

```
curl -w "%{http_code}" -d "url=test" -X POST "http://localhost:80/hashposttest"
Use url: http://nifty-memory-w307.appspot.com/hashget/200okkk@Sprite:~$ 


curl -w "%{http_code}"  -d "url=test" -X POST "https://nifty-memory-268407.appspot.com/hashposttest"

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
500
```

Comment: You should check the log messages in Stackdriver Logging for your app https://console.cloud.google.com/logs

Comment: Any relevant errors on the Stackdriver logs?